# Uso dell'aggettivo "fantomatico"

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, adjectives

All'attuale consiglio comunale di Barcellona piace molto fare assemblee, riunioni, incontri, processi partecipativi, etc. con i cittadini prima di prendere molte decisioni.

Una volta, il proprietario italiano di un piccolo ristorante ci ha spiegato che è andato molte volte a delle riunioni dei proprietari di negozi di ristorazione con i vicini per discutere cosa fare con i tavolini che bar e ristoranti mettono sulla strada. Ci ha detto che a queste riunioni andavano "tre **fantomatici** vicini, sempre gli stessi".

Cercando il [significato di "fantomatico" sul vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/fantomatico) immagino che il significato di questa frase fosse che i vicini assistenti alle riunioni erano talmente pochi che, esagerando un po', quasi non si vedevano. È così? Potreste farmi altri esempi di uso quotidiano del vocabolo "fantomatico"?

Comment: Qual era il problema con la risposta di @abarisone?

Comment: In effetti il mio punto di vista era leggermente diverso da quello di @LinuxBlanket, uno spunto di discussione. Magari non conosceva i vicini ma visto che sembra avessero partecipato ad altre riunioni l'aggetivo fantomatico non mi sembrava appropriato. Io, ad esempio, avrei definito fantomatico il proprietario del più grande ristorante della via che non si faceva mai vedere in giro e improvvisamente si presenta ad una riunione.

Comment: La riattivo solamente per avere ulteriori commenti e suggerimenti a proposito. Sarebbe anche interessante avere la motivazione del voto negativo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Il Nuovo De Mauro, ospitato su Internazionale, dà come [definizione](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/fantomatico):

> 1. simile a un fantasma, spettrale; irreale: figura fantomatica
> 2. estens., che non si sa dove o quando possa comparire o entrare in azione: un fantomatico ladro | non ben identificato: una fantomatica organizzazione terroristica

Direi che l'accezione usata dal ristoratore sia l'ultima, ovvero che lui non conosceva questi vicini e magari non li aveva mai visti nei dintorni.

Oltre agli esempi proposti nella definizione del Nuovo De Mauro, altri esempi di uso potrebbero essere:

> - Mi hanno detto che per avere il timbro sul documento devo andare in un **fantomatico** ufficio in quest'edificio, ma non riesco a trovarlo.
> - Vedi quell'uomo? Si dice che sia possessore di **fantomatiche** ricchezze, anche se va in giro vestito da poveraccio.
> - Dovevo ricevere un **fantomatico** aumento di stipendio, ma non se ne è più fatto nulla.

<sub>Spero che il significato delle varie frasi sia autoevidente; se non è così, le chiarirò.</sub>

Riguardo l'espressione proposta da [abarisone](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/9826/4679), potrebbe essere un regionalismo o caratteristico di una certa area d'Italia, perché io (originaria dell'Italia centrale) non l'ho mai sentita. Direi piuttosto:

> Alle riunioni si presentavano i soliti quattro gatti

per far intendere che le riunioni erano poco frequentate e i partecipanti erano sempre gli stessi.

Comment: Grazie mille della risposta. Potresti fare alcuni altri esempi di uso di "fantomatico" come ho chiesto nella domanda?

Comment: @Charo sì, eccole!